# Metadata Error in Breeze after upgrade

Tags: breeze

I have just upgraded to the latest version of breeze (1.3.5).  I have code that is now failing that was working.  The error:

Metadata import failed for /MyApi/PeopleOrg/Metadata; Unable to process returned metadata:Cannot read property 'name' of null

Here is what is returned by the call to get the Metadata (you will need to format this):

{"schema":{"namespace":"LeonardoMD.Server.Api.People.Org","alias":"Self","d4p1:UseStrongSpatialTypes":"false","xmlns:d4p1":"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation","xmlns":"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm","cSpaceOSpaceMapping":"[[\"LeonardoMD.Server.Api.People.Org.Person\",\"LeonardoMD.Server.Api.People.Org.Person\"],[\"LeonardoMD.Server.Api.People.Org.PersonPhoneNumber\",\"LeonardoMD.Server.Api.People.Org.PersonPhoneNumber\"],[\"LeonardoMD.Server.Api.People.Org.StaffMember\",\"LeonardoMD.Server.Api.People.Org.StaffMember\"],[\"LeonardoMD.Server.Api.People.Org.Contact\",\"LeonardoMD.Server.Api.People.Org.Contact\"]]","entityType":[{"name":"Person","key":{"propertyRef":{"name":"Id"}},"property":[{"name":"Id","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"false","d4p1:StoreGeneratedPattern":"Identity"},{"name":"GlobalPersonId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"UserId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"Inactive","type":"Edm.Boolean","nullable":"false"},{"name":"PrefixId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"FirstName","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"25","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"MiddleName","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"25","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"LastName","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"35","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"SuffixId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"Email","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"80","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"Title","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BirthDate","type":"Edm.DateTime","nullable":"true"},{"name":"SSN","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"20","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"Alias","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"GenderId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"Employer","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"100","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"Occupation","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"100","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"NPI","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"NPIGroup","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"10","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"UPIN","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"TaxIdNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"80","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"TaxIdTypeId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"SpecialtyId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"StateLicenseNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"StateLicenseNumberStateId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"DEA","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"CommercialNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"30","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"CommercialGroupNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"30","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"MedicareNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"MedicareGroupNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"30","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"MedicaidNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"MedicaidGroupNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"30","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BlueShieldNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BlueShieldGroupNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"30","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BlueCrossNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BlueCrossGroupNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"30","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"CHAMPUSNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"Comments","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"3000","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"Verified","type":"Edm.Boolean","nullable":"true"},{"name":"CreateUserId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"CreateDate","type":"Edm.DateTime","nullable":"true"},{"name":"ModifyUserId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"ModifyDate","type":"Edm.DateTime","nullable":"false"}],"navigationProperty":{"name":"PhoneNumbers","relationship":"Self.Person_PhoneNumbers","fromRole":"Person_PhoneNumbers_Source","toRole":"Person_PhoneNumbers_Target"}},{"name":"PersonPhoneNumber","key":{"propertyRef":[{"name":"PersonId"},{"name":"PhoneTypeId"}]},"property":[{"name":"PersonId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"false"},{"name":"PhoneTypeId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"false"},{"name":"PhoneNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"70","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"Extension","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"10","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"OtherDescription","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"25","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"}]},{"name":"StaffMember","key":{"propertyRef":{"name":"Id"}},"property":[{"name":"Id","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"false","d4p1:StoreGeneratedPattern":"Identity"},{"name":"PersonId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"false"},{"name":"Inactive","type":"Edm.Boolean","nullable":"true"},{"name":"StaffMemberTypeId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"Provider","type":"Edm.Boolean","nullable":"true"},{"name":"AllowScheduling","type":"Edm.Boolean","nullable":"true"},{"name":"Coordinator","type":"Edm.Boolean","nullable":"true"},{"name":"MobileEmail","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"80","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"EmailNotificationId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"EmailSignature","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"1000","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"CLIANumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"30","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"HospiceEmployed","type":"Edm.Boolean","nullable":"true"},{"name":"SignatureOnFile","type":"Edm.Boolean","nullable":"true"},{"name":"Signature","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"100","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingNameOld","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingEntityTypeId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingPrefixId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingFirstName","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"25","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingMiddleName","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"25","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingLastName","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"35","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingSuffixId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingAddressLine1","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"55","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingAddressLine2","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"55","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingCity","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"30","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingStateId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingState","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingPostalCode","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"15","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingCountryId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingPhoneNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"70","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"BillingExtension","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"10","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToSameAsBilling","type":"Edm.Boolean","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToEntityTypeId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToPrefixId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToFirstName","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"25","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToMiddleName","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"25","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToLastName","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"35","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToSuffixId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToAddressLine1","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"55","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToAddressLine2","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"55","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToCity","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"30","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToStateId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToState","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToPostalCode","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"15","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToCountryId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToPhoneNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"70","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToExtension","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"10","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToNPI","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"11","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToTaxIdNumber","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"30","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PayToTaxIdTypeId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"VirtuosoEMRGroupId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"VirtuosoEMRDefaultLocationId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"CreateUserId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"CreateDate","type":"Edm.DateTime","nullable":"true"},{"name":"ModifyUserId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"ModifyDate","type":"Edm.DateTime","nullable":"true"}]},{"name":"Contact","key":{"propertyRef":{"name":"Id"}},"property":[{"name":"Id","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"false","d4p1:StoreGeneratedPattern":"Identity"},{"name":"PersonId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"false"},{"name":"Inactive","type":"Edm.Boolean","nullable":"true"},{"name":"ContactTypeId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"PrimaryPhysician","type":"Edm.Boolean","nullable":"true"},{"name":"CreateUserId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"CreateDate","type":"Edm.DateTime","nullable":"true"},{"name":"ModifyUserId","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"true"},{"name":"ModifyDate","type":"Edm.DateTime","nullable":"true"}]}],"association":{"name":"Person_PhoneNumbers","end":[{"role":"Person_PhoneNumbers_Source","type":"Edm.Self.Person","multiplicity":"1","onDelete":{"action":"Cascade"}},{"role":"Person_PhoneNumbers_Target","type":"Edm.Self.PersonPhoneNumber","multiplicity":"*"}],"referentialConstraint":{"principal":{"role":"Person_PhoneNumbers_Source","propertyRef":{"name":"Id"}},"dependent":{"role":"Person_PhoneNumbers_Target","propertyRef":{"name":"PersonId"}}}},"entityContainer":{"name":"PeopleOrgDbContext","entitySet":[{"name":"People","entityType":"Self.Person"},{"name":"PersonPhoneNumbers","entityType":"Self.PersonPhoneNumber"},{"name":"StaffMembers","entityType":"Self.StaffMember"},{"name":"Contacts","entityType":"Self.Contact"}],"associationSet":{"name":"Person_PhoneNumbers","association":"Self.Person_PhoneNumbers","end":[{"role":"Person_PhoneNumbers_Source","entitySet":"People"},{"role":"Person_PhoneNumbers_Target","entitySet":"PersonPhoneNumbers"}]}}}}

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix the issue but I do not know why it required.  I found that the breeze code was failing while processing an association between the Person class and the PersonPhoneNumber class.  I added the entity frameworks [InverseProperty("Phone")] attribute on the PhoneNumbers property in the Person class and added a ForiegnKey("Phone") designation on the PersonId property in the PersonPhoneNumber class and added a new Phone property of type of Phone in the PersonPhoneNumber class.

I guess the lesson:  Make sure to explicitly define association end points in both classes in your entity framework model.

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting the error during import, was the metadata being imported exported using a previous version of Breeze? 
The reason I ask is that the metadata might change from one version to another for various reasons, one being that we are adding support for NoSQL and they have new forms of metadata.

If the above is not the case, could you provide the definition of the 2 entities involved in the issue as well as your import/export code. This way we can try to reproduce the problem here and work on a fix, if determined it's a bug.

Thanks.